# Python2: Get longest Common Prefix path

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to get last matching common path among list of paths below:-

```
"Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.3.0/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/" 
"Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0/aarch64-test-linux-gnu/lib64/"
"Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0/aarch64-unknown-bin"
```

i.e. output should be `Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0`

```
import os
dirs = ["Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.3.0/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/", "Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0/aarch64-test-linux-gnu/lib64/", "Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0/aarch64-unknown-bin"];

prefix = os.path.commonprefix(dirs)

print("Longest common path prefix:", prefix)

print prefix
```

It gives correct output :- `Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0/aarch64-`

But i am expecting `Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0`.
Seems like above API is comparing char by char. Any other suggestions?

Comment: split by path delimiter and just compare each element

Comment: Actually list is huge where its going to increase time complexity if we go with that approach.

Comment: How huge is huge? And the point of time complexity is not care about size. O(n) is O(n)

Comment: You can just split off everything after the last path delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [commonpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath) instead.

```py
>>> os.path.commonpath(dirs)
'Linux-aarch64\\gcc-7.3.0'
```

or can write your own:

```py
>>> def longest_commmon_dir(dirs):
        paths = [path.split('/') for path in dirs]
        min_length = min(len(path) for path in paths)
        for i in range(min_length):
            if not all(path[i] == paths[0][i] for path in paths):
                break
        subdir = '/'.join(paths[0][:i])
        return subdir

>>> longest_commmon_dir(dirs)
'Linux-aarch64/gcc-7.3.0'

>>> longest_commmon_dir(['a', 'b'])
''
```

Comment: `commonpath` works only in python 3. But i am using python 2

Comment: @Kiran then you need to write your own. Take a look at the other example I provided, I think that should work for you.

Comment: @CrazyChucky, Solution would also seems to work in simple approach.